# Run, Debug and do other stuff with Terminal

Tags: ios, terminal

I am new in Ios.
I want to learn how to run , Debug , set break points and lot more using the terminal.
I will appreciate if explanation with example is given.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: This question makes no sense... how "new" are you to iOS?  Have you done any actual iOS programming?  What specifically are you wanting help with?

Comment: Original poster is likely confused on what they're asking. If they're new in iOS, they need to be using Xcode (see my answer below)  If they're new to OS X, then this question is by far too vague. What language do you want to use? What compilers have you installed?

Comment: Yup i am familiar with xcode. and I had pass 3 weaks in ios.also Make some simple app.But have no idea about how to use terminal. I am familiar with windows command prompt.

Comment: Why do you want to use the terminal specifically?  You can do all of these things in XCode.  What is it that you can't do in XCode that you want to do in the terminal?

Comment: @nhgrif Just for learning part.

Comment: @yourwish It's just not something you'll ever need to learn to do. Please see my answer below, which will walk you through how to go about doing what you want to do. Terminal is just NOT the way to go about this, in the same way that Microsoft Word is NOT the way to go about editing a movie.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be doing iOS work in Terminal. Xcode is one of the best (if not the best) IDE you can get. You're working with Objective-C when you're doing iOS, and you're going to need some compilers from Xcode. Impossible to do from Terminal? No, but I don't know why you'd want to do that to yourself.

I recommend checking out Stanford University's iPhone Development classes on iTunes U. They're free, and they're fantastic. It'll walk you through debugging, breakpoints, and running stuff right on your iPhone from Xcode.

Hope that helps, cheers.

**EDIT:**
Let me reiterate, since some folks think that this isn't the droid you're looking for, that you shouldn't really be doing this in Terminal. Your answer is found in iTunes U, or in the iOS developer documentations, which I am happy to provide links to.

Moral of the story: don't do this in Terminal. Just. Don't.

Xcode breakpoints:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/setting_breakpoint_actions_and_options.html

iOS on iTunes U:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: My answer stands thusly. It's not something you should be doing from the terminal, there's no reason to do it, and quite frankly it's likely to lead to major problems down the road when it comes time to submit stuff to Apple, since you'll have files all over the place. I appreciate the down vote though, it's good to know SO hasn't changed.

Comment: While I agree that it shouldn't be done from the terminal, it stands that your answer isn't in fact an answer the asked question even in the slightest.  Good advice?  Sure.  A perfect comment?  Yes.  An answer?  No.  The answer field is for answers, the comment field is for comments.

Comment: I furthermore don't see YOU offering anything worthwhile to the discussion. At least I had the decency to answer the guy with suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know how to run, debug, set breakpoints, or do anything else with the terminal for iOS development, and as such, haven't posted an answer.

Comment: Guess you don't really need to be posting here then, eh?